# Почему в консоль выводится каждое значение(x.y), а не одно окончательное?

Tags: javascript

```js
function sum(x, y) {
  console.log(x + '+' + y + '=' + (x + y));
  return x + y
}
console.log(sum(sum(1, 2), sum(3, sum(4, 5))))
```

```
ВЫВОД в консоль:
"1+2=3"
"4+5=9"
"3+9=12"
"3+12=15"
15
```

Вопрос: почему в части примера, за которую отвечает console.log, выводятся все промежуточные этапы просчёта, а не один окончательный. Как в случае с  return( вывелось сразу 15)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sum(x, y) {
  //console.log(x + '+' + y + '=' + (x + y));
  return x + y
}
console.log(sum(sum(1, 2), sum(3, sum(4, 5))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в коде два раза написано console.log. Один раз в конце - это то, что выводит финальный результат. И один раз в функции, и это то, что выводит текст "1+2=3" при каждом вызове функции.